# Efficient way to merge a data frame with a list of lists based on a key value

Tags: r

I've got a list of lists, each of which has identical structure. One of the elements in each sub-list is a key value. I'd like to add to each sub-list a new element, which is the row of a data frame containing the matching key value. I think this is basically like 'merge', except with one list.

So my list and data frame look like this

```
#Define the list of lists and the data frame
l <- list()
l[[1]] <- list(i=1, data=1:5)
l[[2]] <- list(i=2, data=runif(5))
l[[3]] <- list(i=1, data=rnorm(5))
d <- data.frame(i=c(1, 2), val1=c(TRUE, FALSE), val2 = c("a", "b"))
```

And I'd like to end up with

```
> l_mod[[1]]
$i
[1] 1

$data
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$newData
val1  val2
TRUE     a
```

And so on for each element of `l_mod`, with `$newData` being the appropriate row of `d`. Note that we can assume that each row of `d` has a unique value for `d$i`.

My current approach is to write a matching function and call it from `lapply`

```
matchingRow <- function(indexValue, df) {
  return(df[df$i==indexValue, -1])
}

l_mod <- lapply(l, function(x) c(x, newData=matchingRow(x$i, d)))
```

This basically works, but seems overcomplicated. (Also it splits each column of `d` into a separate element of the new list; I'd rather it place the whole 1-row data frame as a single list element).

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: For the parenthesized statement at the end, you want to use [...,drop=FALSE] when you subset the data frame.  drop=TRUE is the default.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, how does drop come into play here? Isn't it only relevant for matrices and arrays?

Comment: wrap the ```newData=matchingRow(x$i, d)``` in a ```list()``` to prevent the columns of ```d``` being returned as separate list elements. Why define matchingRow though? You can do: ```lapply(l, function(x) c(x, list(newData=d[d$i==x$i, -1])))```

Comment: Right, I thought it made a difference when I ran it, but I had already wrapped the return in list().  Which is what really fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no particular seed.  Seems fine to just take out the extra function call.:

```
l_mod2 <- lapply(l, function(x) list(x, newData=d[d$i==x$i, -1]))

    l_mod2[[3]]
[[1]]
[[1]]$i
[1] 1

[[1]]$data
[1] -0.109289881 -0.577508057  1.416671342 -1.130346543 -0.002256123


$newData
  val1 val2
1 TRUE    a
```

Comment: dunno which is faster, but you can also add a named element to the list:  `lapply(l, function(x) {x$newData=d[d$i==x$i,]; return(x)})`

Comment: Although Drew wanted the returned object to be a list where each element is itself a list containing 3 elements: ```i```, ```data```, and ```newData```. Here, ```i``` and ```data``` are elements of a sub-list (```str(l_mod2)```).